# Find the distinct closest date match for each record from 2 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, closest

Suppose I have Table1 and Table2 with the below data. I want to find the next closest Date match for Table 1(JoiningDt) that is available in Table2.ClosestDt for each ID. Note: Closest Match from Table 2 should be greater than the the date of Table1 and no 2 ID can have the same closest Match(Eg: ID 2 should take the value 08-Apr-2024 even though 07-Apr-2024 is the nearest one because it is already taken by ID 1.)

Table1:

| ID | JoiningDt | DocNum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 05-Apr-2024 | A123 |
| 2 | 06-Apr-2024 | A123 |
| 3 | 04-Apr-2024 | B123 |

Table 2

| DocNum | ClosestDt |
| --- | --- |
| A123 | 03-Apr-2024 |
| A123 | 04-Apr-2024 |
| A123 | 07-Apr-2024 |
| A123 | 08-Apr-2024 |
| B123 | 02-Apr-2024 |
| B123 | 05-Apr-2024 |

My Expected output is:

| ID | JoiningDt | DocNum | ClosestDt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 05-Apr-2024 | A123 | 07-Apr-2024 |
| 2 | 06-Apr-2024 | A123 | 08-Apr-2024 |
| 3 | 04-Apr-2024 | B123 | 05-Apr-2024 |

When I tried an left outer join , I get

| ID | JoiningDt | DocNum | ClosestDt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2024-04-05 | A123 | 2024-04-07 |
| 1 | 2024-04-05 | A123 | 2024-04-08 |
| 2 | 2024-04-06 | A123 | 2024-04-07 |
| 2 | 2024-04-06 | A123 | 2024-04-08 |
| 3 | 2024-04-04 | B123 | 2024-04-05 |

```
select t1.ID ,t1.JoiningDt, t1.DocNum, (t2.ClosestDt)
from #Table1 t1
left join #Table2 t2 on
    t1.DocNum = t2.DocNum
    and t2.ClosestDt > t1.JoiningDt
```

I tried using rownumber also but the challenging part is getting the next match (8-apr and not 7-apr) for id 2 because 7-apr is already taken by Id 1.

Comment: which database system are you using

Comment: SQL - SSIS 2019

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a correlated subquery, where you can pick the nearest date.

For such dynamics, you need to handle the data at least twice.
The basic idea is to use rownumber to determine where two dates a selected two or more tines and then simply choose the next in line, depending on the rownumber it has.

This implies that there ia sufficient data in table 2 to fill the column, else you need some more programming, to determine which dates to take next, after the last.

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 (
  ID INTEGER,
  JoiningDt DATETIME,
  DocNum VARCHAR(4)
);

INSERT INTO Table1
  (ID, JoiningDt, DocNum)
VALUES
  ('1', '05-Apr-2024', 'A123'),
  ('2', '06-Apr-2024', 'A123'),
  ('3', '04-Apr-2024', 'B123');

CREATE TABLE Table2 (
  DocNum VARCHAR(4),
  ClosestDt DATETIME
);

INSERT INTO Table2
  (DocNum, ClosestDt)
VALUES
  ('A123', '03-Apr-2024'),
  ('A123', '04-Apr-2024'),
  ('A123', '07-Apr-2024'),
  ('A123', '08-Apr-2024'),
  ('B123', '02-Apr-2024'),
  ('B123', '05-Apr-2024');
```

```
9 rows affected
```

```
WITH CTE1 As (
SELECT t1.ID, t1.JoiningDt, t1.DocNum,
  (SELECT TOP 1 ClosestDt FROM Table2 
  WHERE DocNum = t1.DocNum AND ClosestDt > t1.JoiningDt ORDER BY ClosestDt  ASC   ) ClosestDt
  , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY DocNum,   (SELECT TOP 1 ClosestDt FROM Table2 
  WHERE DocNum = t1.DocNum AND ClosestDt > t1.JoiningDt ORDER BY ClosestDt  ASC   ) ORDER BY ID) rn
FROM Table1 t1
 )
SELECT ID, JoiningDt, DocNum, 
  CASE WHEN rn = 1 then ClosestDt ELSE
  (SELECT ClosestDt FROM Table2 
  WHERE DocNum = c1.DocNum AND ClosestDt > c1.JoiningDt ORDER BY ClosestDt  ASC   
  OFFSET c1.rn -1  ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY) END 
  FROM CTE1 c1
```

| ID | JoiningDt | DocNum | (No column name) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2024-04-05 00:00:00.000 | A123 | 2024-04-07 00:00:00.000 |
| 2 | 2024-04-06 00:00:00.000 | A123 | 2024-04-08 00:00:00.000 |
| 3 | 2024-04-04 00:00:00.000 | B123 | 2024-04-05 00:00:00.000 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/WkpkLlnZ)

Another  approach with two cte, so that the subselect doesn't run twice, but it is like the first only rewritten

```
WITH CTE1 As (
SELECT t1.ID, t1.JoiningDt, t1.DocNum,
  (SELECT TOP 1 ClosestDt FROM Table2 
  WHERE DocNum = t1.DocNum AND ClosestDt > t1.JoiningDt ORDER BY ClosestDt  ASC   ) ClosestDt
FROM Table1 t1
 ), CTE2 AS (
  SELECT
       ID, JoiningDt, DocNum, ClosestDt
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY DocNum,   ClosestDt ORDER BY ID) rn
  FROM CTE1
  )
SELECT ID, JoiningDt, DocNum, 
  CASE WHEN rn = 1 then ClosestDt ELSE
  (SELECT ClosestDt FROM Table2 
  WHERE DocNum = c1.DocNum AND ClosestDt > c1.JoiningDt ORDER BY ClosestDt  ASC   
  OFFSET c1.rn -1  ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY) END 
  FROM CTE2 c1
```

| ID | JoiningDt | DocNum | (No column name) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2024-04-05 00:00:00.000 | A123 | 2024-04-07 00:00:00.000 |
| 2 | 2024-04-06 00:00:00.000 | A123 | 2024-04-08 00:00:00.000 |
| 3 | 2024-04-04 00:00:00.000 | B123 | 2024-04-05 00:00:00.000 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/KvF6BN_q)

A slow approach that should better be done in a programming language is to use  a cursorm which is a slow approach and with to much rows, this would take a long time, so you should limit the number of rows for table 1

```
DECLARE @ID int
DECLARE @JoiningDt DATETIME
DECLARE @DocNum VARCHAR(4)

DECLARE @MyTableVar TABLE (
    ID INT NOT NULL,
    JoiningDt datetime,
    DocNum VARCHAR(4),
    NearestDate DATETIME);


DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT ID, JoiningDt, DocNum FROM Table1

OPEN db_cursor  
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @ID, @JoiningDt, @DocNum

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
INSERT INTO @MyTableVar
SELECT TOP 1 @ID, @JoiningDt, @DocNum,ClosestDt   FROM table2
WHERE DocNum = @DocNum AND ClosestDt > @JoiningDt     
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM  @MyTableVar WHERE NearestDate  = ClosestDt)
  ORDER BY ClosestDt ASC; 

      FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @ID, @JoiningDt, @DocNum
END 

CLOSE db_cursor  
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
SELECT * FROM @MyTableVar ORDER BY ID
```

| ID | JoiningDt | DocNum | NearestDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2024-04-05 00:00:00.000 | A123 | 2024-04-07 00:00:00.000 |
| 2 | 2024-04-06 00:00:00.000 | A123 | 2024-04-08 00:00:00.000 |
| 3 | 2024-04-04 00:00:00.000 | B123 | 2024-04-05 00:00:00.000 |
| 4 | 2024-04-07 00:00:00.000 | A123 | 2024-04-09 00:00:00.000 |
| 5 | 2024-04-08 00:00:00.000 | A123 | 2024-04-11 00:00:00.000 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/4XwkNH-o)

Comment: This results in both ID no 1 and 2 are having the same ClosestDt (08-Apr-2024). The challenge here is I want Id no 1 to have 07-Apr-2024(as that is the closest to 05-Apr-2024) and for ID no 2 to have 08-Apr-2024 ( even though 07 is the closest ,it has been taken by ID 1)

Comment: Sorry It must be sorted ASC not DESC, I changed the query accordingly

Comment: Still the same problem... Both Id's 1 and 2 have 07-Apr-2024 which isnt the expected output.

Comment: i see your problem, but such a dynamic approach will cost processing time, se my changed answer

Comment: Can you kindly help.. I am getting the following error in the below situation
|:ID  |JoiningDt                          |DocNum|rn   |(No column name)         |
|:-----|:--------------------------------:|:-------:|:----:|------------------------:|
|1 |2024-04-05 00:00:00.000  |A123    |1     |2024-04-07 00:00:00.000  |
|2 |2024-04-06 00:00:00.000  |A123    |2     |2024-04-08 00:00:00.000  |
|4 |2024-04-07 00:00:00.000  |A123    |3     |2024-04-09 00:00:00.000  |
|5 |2024-04-08 00:00:00.000  |A123    |1     |2024-04-08 00:00:00.000  |

Comment: whereas ID no 5 needs to have the next available date from table 2 which is 10-Apr-2024 but now both ID num 2 and 5 have the same closestdate. I understand the reason but unable to solve it.

Comment: Please make a fiddle for that see link in my answer

Comment: please copy your data hee https://dbfiddle.uk/KvF6BN_q  and post the new lonk, comments are a very bad place to post data

Comment: Yes, https://dbfiddle.uk/tX-LRGhR .. pls check the ID num 2 and 4 ..ID num 4 should be having the value 9-Apr-2024 and thereby ID 5 as 11-Apr-2024

Comment: for that you need to run row by row, which can be done in a stored procedure and a loop or on application level

Comment: @PoornaPrakash i added a more dynamic but slwo apporach

Comment: Thank you.. yes, its slower but the output works as expected.